# How to get user's information on WebAPI controller after authenticated with IdentityServer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, jwt, identityserver3

I cannot get user's information on WebAPI controller after my client app authenticates with IdentityServer3 successfully. Below are the steps:

1. "Login With Profile and Access Token" successfully from [JavaScript Implicit Client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/JavaScriptImplicitClient) app
2. I see user's data on "ID Token Contents" panel
   [image]
3. I do "Call service" to my WebAPI service, I see many claims in ClaimsPrincipal but cannot get values such as email, roles displayed on client side. Below are code & responses.

[image]
Could anyone provide me some helps how to get user's data on WebAPI?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

if you use owin, you can try this code.

```
 var owinUser = TryGetOwinUser();
 var claim= TryGetClaim(owinUser, "email");
 string email = claim.Value;

 private ClaimsPrincipal TryGetOwinUser()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            return null;

        var context = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext();
        if (context == null)
            return null;

        if (context.Authentication == null || context.Authentication.User == null)
            return null;

        return context.Authentication.User;
    }

    private Claim TryGetClaim(ClaimsPrincipal owinUser, string key)
    {
        if (owinUser == null)
            return null;

        if (owinUser.Claims == null)
            return null;

        return owinUser.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Type.Equals(key));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, @Serdar. I can get owincontext like your code but claims are the same. There are claims with Type=scope and Value = email, no one with Type = email as you said. Do you have other idea?

Comment: Claims does not email information. You can add claim("email") to claims when login

Comment: The login is done by IdentityServer, I don't know what is the email in my WebAPI service. You see on a sample client app, it can parse from token all information, included email address and roles http://i.stack.imgur.com/mwSCi.png

Comment: yes, it's on github https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/tree/master/source/Core but I haven't look on it yet :)

Comment: you find login function on identity app. you can edit claims.https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Endpoints/AuthenticationController.cs

Comment: I found that method. Is it possible to parse the token and get information? maybe OIDC client does that. do you think so ?

Comment: what  is  controlller name and function name ? login method?

Comment: you ask about the link mentioned above? the function is private void IssueAuthenticationCookie(string signInMessageId, AuthenticateResult authResult, bool? rememberMe = null)
        {...}

Comment: Please talk in this room if it's possible with you @Serdar http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82185/discussion-between-serdar-catalpinar-and-hazjack

Comment: you can edit this function("IssueAuthenticationCookie"). There are places  claim added in the code . you must add email info as claim.Debug mode, you can do it... verry easy...