# Ws-Federation Identity Information Not Available in Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Ws-Fed Authentication OWIN middleware to authenticate an ASP.NET MVC app with Web API endpoints using ADFS.  I'm able to sign in using ADFS successfully, and on my MVC controllers, HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true - I can see the claims information for the signed in user as well.

However for WebAPI endpoints, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false.  The claims information for the signed is user is also unavailable.  Is there any way that I expose the fact that the user is authenticated for both MVC and WebAPI controllers?

Here is how I am configuring my authentication middleware in the OWIN Startup class:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(sessionDuration), 
            SlidingExpiration = true //expiration extended after each request
        });

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = metadata,
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/?loginfailed=loginfailed");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I discovered the answer to this question by examining the OWIN cookie authentication middleware source code on [CodePlex](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs).  Cookies created using the middleware by an MVC controller are created differently from cookies created Web API.  MVC cookies are a reference to user information stored in session, and since Web API is completely stateless (no session), cookies created in MVC can not be used in Web API.

In addition, it is bad practice to use cookie authentication in Web API anyways; bearer token authentication is a preferable option.

In my case where I needed to use Ws-Federation authentication, the solution was to:

1. Add bearer token authentication middleware to my app
2. Create a Web API endpoint (ideally cryptically named) that will securely receive Ws-Federation claims, perform validation to ensure the request really came from your MVC controller, use them to generate a bearer token, and respond with the generated bearer token
3. Upon authenticating in MVC, serialize the claims, and marshal them over to Web API using the endpoint created earlier
4. Add the bearer token to a hidden field in the SPA

Many, many thanks to @Juan for providing me with feedback and links to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code for how to get claims after ADFS login page? Or point me to some articles/posts?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "Name Id" claim to ADFS:

http://darb.io/blog/2014/06/30/WebAPI-and-ADFS-as-external-login-provider/

Comment: It's not that I'm afraid.  I even tried sending Name ID as the only claim; even that did not work -- MVC controllers say isAuthenticated = true, Web API says false :(

Comment: I tested this locally and it works for me. If possible, get the following three values from within one of your Web Api controllers and let me know what you get: Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, 
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. I read somewhere that the first two need to be set for Web Api.

Comment: Check this one out too. There might be something buried in there that an help you figure it out: http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Configuring_ADFS_3.0_to_Communicate_with_SAML_2.0#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion.  Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IdentityIsAuthenticated, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated are all false.  The fact that it works for you gives me hope.  Can I see your startup.cs code for a sample?  I must be missing something...

Comment: I am using Asp.Net Identity so the setup is different and unfortunately it won't help you. The reason why I asked about all those values is that these should be set by your authentication method for Web Api to work so review your code and make sure you are not overriding it and that OWIN is setting it correctly. Try getting the OWIN context too and see if that one has the User: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160965/how-to-get-users-information-on-webapi-controller-after-authenticated-with-iden

Comment: @Juan: Do you know how to achieve the second part "Linking up to Web API external login" in the blog post?

Comment: @Khoait: Not sure but I think once you configure the prior step in the blog, the authentication redirection should happen automatically for you.

Comment: @Juan: Yes, I did and it's working. Now I want to store the claims returned from ADFS such as first name and last name into user table in database so that I can assign roles to the user. I think linking up to web API external login will help. Do you have any idea how I can achieve it?

Comment: @Khoait: I see. You should be getting that information in the claims. If not, you need to ask the ADFS admin to add the claims so you can grab them from the User's identity object. You shouldn't have to poll the server again at all. That's the idea behind claims. First Name is a claim, Last Name is a claim, Full Name could be another claim.

Comment: @Juan: Thanks! I'll give it a try.